# IF statement to determine date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to set an order completion date based on the words Standard or Rush.

Currently I have it set up where if a cell shows the word Standard, it will give me a date, but once I try to add Rush to that, it get errors

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("VF",B2)), IF(J2="Standard", WORKDAY(TODAY( )+2,1)), "")
```

I also tried this, but when I type Rush into `J2`, the result shows as just `FALSE`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("VF",B2)), (IF(J2="Standard", WORKDAY(TODAY( )+2,1))), (IF(J2="Rush", WORKDAY(TODAY( )+1,1))))
```

The idea here is to make an order wanted date based on the Rush and Standard time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have embedded your new `IF` function inside of the wrong if.

This: `(IF(J2="Standard", WORKDAY(TODAY( )+2,1)))` is going to return a date or FALSE. You want to change that `FALSE` to return your next IF statement. Instead:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("VF",B2)), IF(J2="Standard", WORKDAY(TODAY( )+2,1), IF(J2="Rush", WORKDAY(TODAY( )+1,1))), "")
```

You return nothing `""` in the case that your `ISNUMBER()` fails still.